# Stop Thread in Kotlin

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, handler

First of all, I'm new in Kotlin, so please be nice :).
It's also my first time posting on StackOverflow

I want to literally **STOP** the current thread that I created but nothing works.

I tried `quit()`, `quitSafely()`, `interrupt()` but nothing works.

I created a class (`Data.kt`), in which I create and initialize a `Handler` and `HandlerThread` as follows :

```kotlin
class Dispatch(private val label: String = "main") {

    var handler: Handler? = null
    var handlerThread: HandlerThread? = null

    init {
        if (label == "main") {
            handlerThread = null
            handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        } else {
            handlerThread = HandlerThread(label)
            handlerThread!!.start()
            handler = Handler(handlerThread!!.looper)
        }
    }

    fun async(runnable: Runnable) = handler!!.post(runnable)

    fun async(block: () -> (Unit)) = handler!!.post(block)

    fun asyncAfter(milliseconds: Long, function: () -> (Unit)) {
        handler!!.postDelayed(function, milliseconds)
    }

    fun asyncAfter(milliseconds: Long, runnable: Runnable) {
        handler!!.postDelayed(runnable, milliseconds)
    }

    companion object {
        val main = Dispatch()
        private val global = Dispatch("global")
        //fun global() = global
    }
}
```

And now, in my `DataManager`, I use these to do asynchronous things :

```kotlin
fun getSomething(forceNetwork: Boolean ) {

    val queue1 = Dispatch("thread1") // Create a thread called "thread1"
    queue1.async {
        for (i in 0..2_000_000) {
             print("Hello World")
             // Do everything i want in the current thread
        }

        // And on the main thread I call my callback
        Dispatch.main.async {
            //callback?.invoke(.........)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in my `MainActivity`, I made 2 buttons :

1. One for running the function `getSomething()`
2. The other one is used for switching to another Controller View :

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
button.setOnClickListener {
    DataManager.getSomething(true)
}

val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
button2.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, Test::class.java) // Switch to my Test Controller
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

Is there a way to stop the thread, because when I switch to my second View, `print("Hello World")` is still triggered, unfortunately.

Thanks for helping me guys I hope that you understand !

Comment: Can you post full Diapatch class code?

Comment: I edited it ,you have now the full class code

Comment: Once `getSomething()` returns, the thread will stop, won't it? So you just need a flag for it to watch inside the loop, and return when it changes value.

Comment: Yes if getSomething() returns the thread will stop. Which flag should I use please ? I don't really see , I want to stop the process in the loop when I'm on another Activity

Answer (score 3):

A thread needs to periodically check a (global) flag and when it becomes true then the thread will break out from the loop. Java threads cannot be safely stopped without its consent.

Refer to page 252 here http://www.rjspm.com/PDF/JavaTheCompleteReference.pdf that describes the true story behind the legend.

I think that a truly interruptible thread is only possible through the support of the operating system kernel. The actual true lock is held deep down by the CPU hardware microprocessor.

Comment: This was really helpful